# Storing the path of depth first search in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to write a DFS for a rectangular grid where in I start from a certain (x,y) coordinate and have to reach the goal coordinate(xg,yg). I need my function to return a path which is actually a list of directions that I have taken,like

---

```
action=['Up','Left','Left','Bottom']
```

---

My code so far goes like this

---

```
def depthFirstSearch():
    visited=[]                # stores the vertices that I have visited  
    action=[]                 # this is what I have to return
    stack=Stack()             # the general stack used in DFS
    forward=Stack()           # stores the forward direction 
    reverse=Stack()           # stores the backward direction, in case we need to backtrack
    stack.push(getStartState())

    while not stack.isEmpty():
        tmp=stack.pop()
        if(GoalState(tmp)):
            return action
        if not tmp in visited:
            visited.append(tmp)
            if not forward.isEmpty():
                dirn=forward.pop()
                action.append(dirn)
                reverse.append(opposite(dirn))

        child1=getSuccessors(tmp)   # returns all the possible childs and direction as a list
        child2=[]

        for st in child1:
            if not st in visited:
                child2.append(st)

        if child2:
            for state in child2:
                stack.push(state[0])
                forward.push(state[1])
                reverse.push(oppposite(state[1])
        elif not child2:
            action.append(reverse.pop())
```

---

I am new to python and would be really appreciate if somebody could help me out here. I am having problems with the indentation. Also I am not very sure about the logic of my DFS for storing the path. Please help !!

Comment: Please, indent your code correctly so that we can follow your ideas.  Should all of your snippet be inside `depthFirstSearch`?

Comment: Hopefully, this will make it clear. Sorry about earlier !

Comment: Your question is not so clear.  Do you mean that the path needs to include backtracking when the search reaches a dead end?

Comment: @Gene: Yes.. That is where the problem is. It must backtrack

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that explains about [Depth First Search](http://en.literateprograms.org/Depth-first_search_%28Python%29). What you do is the following, you have `start` node, in your case `(x,y)` and then you check if the steps you visit has has reached the `goal` which is `(xg,yg)` The way depth first search does is, it maintains a stack and pushes each visited node into the stack and pops them out and check's if it is goal. In your program you will have to write that checking step into the list. I hope that tutorial link helps you get started.

Comment: The problem here is, say I am on the node (x,y) which has two childs (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) both of which are not goal states. Now, when I go to (x1,y1), from there I cannot directly go to (x2,y2). I first need to come back to (x,y) and then again go back to (x2,y2).

Comment: Try to treat x1,y1 as a single node, at tuple or a two element list.

Comment: When you are on (x,y) the reachable states are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), so you push them both to the stack. Now you pop one at a time, say (x1,y1) and now look for reachable states from there and so on go "Depth First". Try that Link which I pointed out.

Comment: Nope. I am not, already busy with many things. But let me check that out. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17993/discussion-between-csss-and-senthil-kumaran)